# Ensuring security in Token url authentication

Tags: authentication

I am trying to make provision for resetting password if the user forgets his password. What I did is make a html page(say email.html) where the user will enter his email address. When the user submits his email address the webpage forwards it to a servlet, lets call it forgot_pass.java. Then a unique 128bit alpha numeric string (say id) is created. This string along with url of forgot_pass.java (like url?id=21345...) is send to the user's email address. Upon clicking on the link, servlet forgot_pass.java checks if the id is valid or not and also checks if it expired or not. If it passes above mentioned checks then the user is forwarded to another html page (lets call this one re-enter.html). In this page the user can enter his email id, enter password twice and submit. This concludes the process.

My concern is if anyone access re-enter.html, wont he be able to change his password ?
How can I improve security ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got sounds at a basic level, how many people handle password resets.  A couple of things to consider.

- Tokens should only be valid for one user. i.e. you shouldn't have a pool of "valid reset tokens" but a list of token-->username mappings. So when someone accesses page one you can tie that to the account they should have clicked the link from.
- when the user successfully uses the forgotten password link, after checking their token you should set a session token for them, and then check for a valid session token when loading the second page.  That way if anyone tries to directly access the second page they won't be able to use it without a valid session
- you should pre-populate the E-Mail ID for the second page based on the user who's token is being accessed.  Otherwise there's a risk that one user can reset anothers password.
- Once the token has been successfully used you should invalidate it to prevent someone who comes across it in future from resetting the users password again
- You should have an "unused" token expiry to prevent them from being permanently useful.
- One user account should only have one valid token at a time.  If a user has one issued, and they go through the process again it should overwrite the first token.

Comment: I am using an UPSERT based on user id so each user id has only one token associated with it at a time. Also, I am currently using a random function rand() which is a library funtion to make a 128 bit value, Is that safe ?

Comment: I'd say that if you're using a 128-bit random value for this kind of function it should be ok.